# Steam games with multiple dualshock controllers?

Tags: steam, controllers

I'm now using dualshock 4 as a controller to play my games on steam, but is it possible to play with two controllers on steam games too? Like you play multi player games with 2 controllers on a PS4?

Comment: If the game supports it, then it should be possible, but I doubt that you will find many games (if any) which support it for PC

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to say for specific games since you didn't mention which ones. Some may not have controller support or not allow multiple controllers.

In general though, connecting multiple controllers to a pc is possible. PS4 controllers may require additional software, but this is capable of supporting multiple controllers at once.